# Dúvida sobre atributos do input no HTML

Tags: php, html, input

Olá, pessoal. Estou fazendo uma Tabuada usando HTML e PHP.
O usuário digita um número através de formulário e é exibida a tabuada deste.
Gostaria de saber se consigo colocar algum atributo no `<input type="number>"`para que seja exibido somente números positivos no campo de seleção do usuário. Hoje meu código está assim:

```
<!--CAMPO PARA DIGITAR O NÚMERO-->
    <label>Número:</label>
    <input type="number" name="numero">
```

Desde já, agradeço!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As propriedades **min** e **max** de um input definem os valores mínimos e máximos, respectivamente.
`<input type="number" min="0" name="numero">`

Comment: Obrigada, Thiago. Ajudou muito!

Answer (score 2):

Sendo o input do tipo `number`, você pode definir os valores mínimos e máximos através dos atributos `min` e `max`, respectivamente.

```html
<input type="number" name="numero" min="0" max="9">
```

Se desejar qualquer valor positivo, basta remover o atributo `max`.

Comment: Obrigada, Anderson. Ajudou muito!

Answer (score 2):

Como o usuário Thiago já respondeu, você pode utilizar os atributos `min` e `max` do HTML5.

O único problema é que eles não vão funcionar em navegadores mais antigos.
Nestes casos é sempre interessante utilizar um polyfill para garantir que os navegadores mais antigos também tenham a funcionalidade.

Um plugin bacana para jQuery que tem uma compatibilidade é o [Stepper](https://formstone.it/components/number/).

Comment: Obrigada, @jHertel. Vou ficar atenta a isso!